# Take value from input and set it to another input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using date range picker, here is the link of my codepen http://codepen.io/kylecraven1/pen/yaJZLk if you click on pick up date, you can see two calendars there, I want that second calendar input in drop off date box.

Here what I did, but it's not working

```
$(".applyBtn").click(function(){
var myEndDate = $("input[name=daterangepicker_end]").val();
$("input[name=dropoffdate]").val(myEndDate);
});
```

Comment: Why you put variable name inside ' ' ?

Comment: @mtch9 I accidentally wrote that quotes, just removed from question. Still same not working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're assigning a string instead of the contents of myEndDate.
You should replace:

`$("input[name=dropoffdate]").val('myEndDate');`

with

`$("input[name=dropoffdate]").val(myEndDate);`

Notice I've removed the quotes from `myEndDate`

Comment: I accidentally wrote that quotes, just removed from question. Still same not working.